# How to install/enable GMP (math functions) for PHP on CentOS

Tags: php, vps, centos7, packages

I am trying to install GMP (GNU Multiple Precision) for PHP on my VPS.
Server OS :- CentOS 6 with cPanel
GMP Official Site :- http://www.gmplib.org
I have been trying from 8 Days, but have not found any solution.

Comment: Please include what you have tried into your question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are missing and need GMP itself, you can install GMP from the **CentOS Base repository**.

```
yum -y install gmp
```

---

As for the php-gmp package, it is not available in the standard CentOS 6 Base repository. You either have to create it yourself which can be tedious, or use a non-standard repository which includes it.

---

**NOTE:**
Do know that this will **replace** the standard PHP 5.3 version from CentOS with a newer version maintained by **Remi's RPM repository**.

It's adviced to run minimum **PHP 5.6** as this is not EOL until December 2018.

---

The easy solution is to install from another repository (**REMI repository**) instead.

This requires you to have the **EPEL repository** installed first.

```
yum -y install epel-release
```

Then continue to install **REMI Repository** and yum-utils (to configure PHP version).

```
yum -y install http://rpms.remirepo.net/enterprise/remi-release-6.rpm
yum -y install yum-utils
```

To enable the **PHP 5.6** repository.

```
yum-config-manager --enable remi-php56
```

Upgrade all your installed PHP packages by upgrading the system.

```
yum -y upgrade
```

Then finally install the php-gmp package.

```
yum -y install php-gmp
```

- https://rpms.remirepo.net/wizard/

Comment: thank you so much for answering my question.
but it shows No package php-gmp available
https://prnt.sc/fizr1h

Comment: Hold on a minute, is this a cPanel server? I see you have cPanel related repositories and seem to be using EasyApache 4.

Comment: Can you please post the output of: php -v

Comment: output of **php -v**
http://prntscr.com/fj02f6

Comment: So for cPanel you should *NOT* be fiddling with things like these manually. Remove REMI with: 'yum -y remove remi-release' then run 'yum -y install ea-php56-php-gmp'. If you have multiple PHP versions installed, and the site is not using 5.6 replace "56" with the version it's using.

This can also be done via WHM, see "EasyApache 4" in the menu.

If you get stuck, you should contact the Datacenter/cPanel support (depending on whom issued the license) for further assistance in this matter.

Comment: installed.. and working..
Thank you so much so much so much .. you saved my days,.,

Comment: can you give me any contact  ?

Comment: Happy to hear! Just ask on serverfault if you need help with something and I might answer next time too. :-)

Please if you can, mark the answer as correct (as it is as long as you don't run cPanel).

I'm not sharing my contact information just yet on serverfault. Maybe I will in the future, on the profile.

Comment: check this Question
https://serverfault.com/questions/855366/cpanel-not-opening-after-successfully-installation-on-google-cloud-compute